# "not visibile individually" products showing up on front end

Tags: magento-1.9, import

I am importing a bunch of skus into magento. I worked out a system to finally get it working properly with images that work etc.

However I stopped after a while and now I came back to it, and after importing a bunch of skus that are not supposed to be visible individually, they all show on the front end of the site.

I checked the product in admin, and the option is selected to not show individually.

another issue I am having.. that I had before but I thought I fixed. The country_of_manufacture column is not being imported. The last time that did not work I had to make sure that the country "Canada" was an option in the country_of_manufacture attribute. Which it is now.. But I am getting that issue again.

Comment: Have you checked individual store scopes?

Answer (score 1):

> “not visibile individually” products showing up on front end

One question per question please.

Please make sure, that there is a value for `visibility` in the database and that `not visibile individually` is not just the default. Magento might filter for that value (which then doesn't exist)

No clue about the second problem. Digging into it with xdebug helped me with such problems.

You may use the following code (thanks swapna taru)

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
    ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCol‌​lection($collection);
```

Comment: Sorry about the 2 questions. i thought they possible might be related. Do you know where in the database the visibility is set? I don't think that is the issue though, because when I go into the product in admin I see that the option is selected correctly.

Comment: I just switched to English/French in admin and I see that visibility is set to search/advanced search. sooo not sure why they are being set differently than the import/default setting.

Comment: visibility is saved in `catalog_product_entity_int` but you can check, by just saving the product and check again, after index, whether it is still visible in frontend

Comment: You may use the following code - Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);